# Document-Term Matrix with Quanteda

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, quanteda

I have a dataframe df with this structure :

```
Rank Review
5    good film
8    very goood film
..
```

Then I tried to create a DocumentTermMatris using quanteda package  :

```
temp.tf <- df$Review %>% tokens(ngrams = 1:1) %>% # generate tokens
+   dfm %>% # generate dfm
+   convert(to = "tm")
```

I get this matrix :

```
> inspect(temp.tf)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 63023, terms: 23892)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 520634/1505224882
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 77
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
```

Whith this structure :

```
           Terms
Docs        good very film my excellent heart David plus always so
  text14670 1       0      0      0   1          0      0    0        2    0
  text19951 3       0      0      0   0          0      0    1        1    1
  text24305 7       0      2      1   0          0      0    2        0    0
  text26985 6       0      0      0   0          0      0    4        0    1
  text29518 4       0      1      0   1          0      0    3        0    1
  text34547 5       2      0      0   0          0      2    3        1    3
  text3781  3       0      1      4   0          0      0    3        0    0
  text5272  4       0      0      4   0          5      0    3        1    2
  text5367  3       0      1      3   0          0      1    4        0    1
  text6001  3       0      9      1   0          6      0    1        0    1
```

So I think It is good , but I think that  :  text6001 , text5367, text5272 ... refer to document's name...
My question is that rows in this matrix are ordered? or randoms putted in the matrix?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

I created a document term frequency :

```
mydfm <- dfm(df$Review, remove = stopwords("french"), stem = TRUE)
```

Then, I created a tf-idf matrix :

```
tfidf <- tfidf(mydfm)[, 5:10]
```

Then I would like to merge the tfidf matrix to the Rank column to have something like this

```
         features
Docs        good   very   film   my excellent heart    David plus  always so Rank
  text14670 1       0      0      0   1          0      0    0        2    0 3
  text19951 3       0      0      0   0          0      0    1        1    1 2
  text24305 7       0      2      1   0          0      0    2        0    0 4
  text26985 6       0      0      0   0          0      0    4        0    1 5
```

Can you help to make this merge?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows (documents) are alphabetically ordered, which is why `text14670` comes before `text19951`.  It is possible that the conversion has reordered the documents, but you can test this using

```
sum(rownames(temp.tf) == sort(rownames(temp.tf))
```

If that is not 0, then they are not alphabetically ordered.

The feature ordering, at least in the **quanteda** dfm, come from the order in which they are found in the texts.  You can resort both using `dfm_sort()`.

In your code, the `tokens(ngrams = 1:1)` is unnecessary since `dfm()` does that and `ngrams = 1` is the default.

Also, do you need to convert this to a **tm** object?  Probably most of what you need can be done in **quanteda**.

Comment: Thank you, last question .. is it possible with Quanteda to create tf-idf matrix? Bests

Comment: I just edit my post, can you help to resolve my  problem please?  thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking - what is `Rank`? _tf-idf_ is cell-specific, so you cannot covert that into a document-level feature (with one value per document). I suggest starting a new SO question and making it more clear what output you expect, with a reproducible example.